# Limit of a monotonically increasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> $(a_n)$ is a monotonically increasing sequence which doesn't  converge. Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n =+\infty$.

Idea:
We know, if a monotonically increasing sequence is bounded, then it has a limit.
That means, that $a_n$ can't be bounded, otherwise it would be converge.

Is my idea correct?

Comment: $a_n$ is unbound, it's true. But it doesn't mean that $a_n\to\infty$. For monotonically increasing sequence it's true, but you should to prove it.

Comment: What you say is correct, but you're not quite done. You've shown the sequence is unbounded. _Now_ you have to show that that implies that the sequence actually tends to $\infty$. (They're not the same thing. For example the sequence $0,1,0,2,0,3,\dots$ is unbounded but does _not_ tend to infinity.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=+\infty$ if for all $M>0$, there exists $N$ such that $n\geqslant N$ implies $a_n > M$.

So let $M>0$. You've shown that $\{a_n\}$ is unbounded, so $M$ cannot be an upper bound for $\{a_n\}$. Therefore there exists an $N$ such that $a_N > M$. Then if $n\geqslant N$, $$a_n\geqslant a_N > M,$$ so that $a_n\to+\infty$.